# Time series group comparison

Tags: time-series, group-differences

I am currently analyzing a time-series experiment and I have some difficulties to come with a nice comparison of my groups. I was hoping someone could help me. The design is the following:

Three groups of 10 individuals are analyzed with the same technic at 15 timepoints. For each individuals at each timepoint we obtain a table of occurence such as:

```
Genomic position  Number of occurence
chr1 100
chr2 50
chr20 10
```

Which merged for one individual gives:

```
Genomic position    Time1   Time2   Time3   Time4 ...
chr1    100 0   0   0
chr2    50  10  25  50
chr20   10  20  30  100
```

Those positions should be mainly different between individuals even in the same group.

I would like to know if there is a way to compare the evolution of these occurrences accross time between the groups?

My final goal is to know if for example these observations are more maintained in one group or if they quickly disappear after the first observation in one group more than another.

Could you please guide me to some statistical tests or readings that could help me to solve this issue?

Comment: How many genomic events on average you have per sample and time point ?

Comment: We have on average ~4000 (+/- 6500) events per animal. Each time point bring between dozens and several thousands of new genomic events.